# Google Chrome Frame - How can you detect when GCF fails to install (general failure, or blocked)

Tags: google-chrome-frame

Is there any way you can detect if the installation of Google Chrome Frame fails, or was blocked? I am using the CFInstall script. Here's my implementation:

```
CFInstall.check(
{
    preventPrompt: true,
    destination: window.location.toString(),

    onmissing: function ()
    {
        /* User clicks a button, iframe is shown... */
    }
});
```

...

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/chromeframe/eula.html?user=true"
        id="googlechromeframe"
        name="googlechromeframe"></iframe>
```

Note that I am pointing users to the user-specific installer, which doesn't require admin-privileges. The installation can still be blocked though...